# C socket programming: select() is returning 0 despite messages sent from server

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, select-function

I'm using `select()` to `recv()` messages from server, using TCP/IP.  When I `send()` messages from the server, it returns a reasonable number of bytes, saying it's sent successful. And it does get to the client successfully when I use `while` loop to just `recv()`. Everything is fine and dandy.

```
while(1)
   recv() // obviously pseudocode
```

However, when I try to use `select()`, `select()` returns 0 from timeout (which is set to 1 second) and for the life of me I cannot figure out why it doesn't see the messages sent from the server. I should also mention that when the server disconnects, `select()` doesn't see that either, where as if I were to use `recv()`, it would return 0 to indicate that the connection using the socket has been closed. Any inputs or thoughts are deeply appreciated.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define SERVER_PORT 10000
#define MAX_CONNECTION  20
#define MAX_MSG     50


struct client
{
    char c_name[MAX_MSG];
    char g_name[MAX_MSG];

int csock;
int host;   // 0 = not host of a multicast group    

struct sockaddr_in client_address;

struct client * next_host;
struct client * next_client;    
};

struct fd_info
{
char c_name[MAX_MSG];

int socks_inuse[MAX_CONNECTION];
int sock_fd, max_fd;
int exit;

struct client * c_sys;
struct sockaddr_in c_address[MAX_CONNECTION];

struct sockaddr_in server_address;
struct sockaddr_in client_address;

fd_set read_set;
};

struct message
{
char c_name[MAX_MSG];
char g_name[MAX_MSG];
char _command[3][MAX_MSG];
char _payload[MAX_MSG];

struct sockaddr_in client_address;
struct client peer;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
char * host;
char * temp;

int i, sockfd;
int msg_len, rv, ready;
int connection, management, socketread;
int sockfds[MAX_CONNECTION];


// for three threads that handle new connections, user inputs and select() for sockets
pthread_t connection_handler, manager, socket_reader;

struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;
struct hostent * hserver, cserver;
struct timeval timeout;
struct message msg;
struct fd_info info;
info.exit = 0;  // exit information: if exit = 1, threads quit
info.c_sys = NULL;

// looking up from the host database
if (argc == 3)
{
    host = argv[1];         // server address
    strncpy(info.c_name, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]));     // client name
}
else
{
    printf("plz read the manual, kthxbai\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("host is %s and hp is %p\n", host, hserver);
hserver = gethostbyname(host);
if (hserver)
{
    printf("host found: %s\n", hserver->h_name );
}
else
{
    printf("host not found\n");
    exit(1);
}
// setting up address and port structure information on serverside
bzero((char * ) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)); // copy zeroes into string
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
memcpy(&server_address.sin_addr, hserver->h_addr, hserver->h_length);
server_address.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

bzero((char * ) &client_address, sizeof(client_address)); // copy zeroes into string
client_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
client_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
client_address.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

// opening up socket
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
    exit(1);
else
{
    printf("socket is opened: %i \n", sockfd);
    info.sock_fd = sockfd;
}

// sets up time out option for the bound socket 
timeout.tv_sec = 1;     // seconds
timeout.tv_usec = 0; // micro seconds ( 0.5 seconds)
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(struct timeval));

// binding socket to a port
rv = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, sizeof(client_address));
if (rv < 0)
{
    printf("MAIN: ERROR bind() %i: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
else
    printf("socket is bound\n");

printf("MAIN: %li \n", client_address.sin_addr.s_addr);


// connecting
rv = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
info.server_address = server_address;
info.client_address = client_address;
info.sock_fd = sockfd;
info.max_fd = sockfd;
printf("rv = %i\n", rv);
if (rv < 0)
{
    printf("MAIN: ERROR connect() %i:  %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
else
    printf("connected\n");

fd_set readset;
FD_ZERO(&readset);
FD_ZERO(&info.read_set);
FD_SET(info.sock_fd, &info.read_set);

while(1)
{
    readset = info.read_set;
    printf("MAIN: %i \n", readset);
    ready = select((info.max_fd)+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    if(ready == -1)
    {
        sleep(2);
        printf("TEST: MAIN: ready = -1. %s \n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else if (ready == 0)
    {
        sleep(2);
        printf("TEST: MAIN: ready = 0. %s \n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else if (ready > 0)
    {
        printf("TEST: MAIN: ready = %i. %s at socket %i \n", ready, strerror(errno), i);
        for(i = 0; i < ((info.max_fd)+1); i++)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(i, &readset))
            {
                rv = recv(sockfd, &msg, 500, 0);
                if(rv < 0)
                    continue;
                else if(rv > 0)
                    printf("MAIN: TEST: %s %s \n", msg._command[0], msg._payload);
                else if (rv == 0)
                {
                    sleep(3);
                    printf("MAIN: TEST: SOCKET CLOSEDDDDDD \n");
                }

                FD_CLR(i, &readset);
            }
        }

    }
    info.read_set = readset;        

}

// close connection
close(sockfd);
printf("socket closed. BYE! \n");
return(0);

}
```

Comment: You're going to have to make the test case a bit smaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a timeout ever occurs, then your `readset` will end up with no file descriptors set.  You then replace `info.read_set` with this empty set:

```
info.read_set = readset;
```

..and so you're always checking an empty file descriptor set after that, which means you'll timeout every time.

(By the way, you're not really supposed to assign file descriptor sets around like that - there's no guarantee that they don't contain structures that need to be deep-copied.  The portable approach is to build the file descriptor set up from scratch each time.)

Comment: I thought I'd do that because I've read it that it's just a bit array. I don't remember the exact error but when I tried copying it using `for` loop to copy element by element, it gave me an error.

Comment: Wow, I'm not even sure why I wrote that... But that definitely did fix the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Some platforms provide an `FD_COPY()` macro for making a copy of an `fd_set`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing:

Either increase the time-out value or keep that as NULL.

I guess it will become blocking socket as select waits in that call until some thing is existing to read from peer. Just try this is one of the options. I think increasing the time-out value is the feasible solution.